# Libgdx Array contains like

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx

I am using Libgdx's Array to store my own 'Coordinate' class. In another class I am making reference to that Array, to see if there is a "block" in the player's vision line. I have the line programming all done, but I cannot seem to find out how to see if the Array contains a 'Coordinate' like the temporary one I have. I seem to have gotten it working with

```
if(hex.getWorld().get(0).equals(tmp)) {
    System.out.println("break");
    break;
}
```

but that only works with one of the 'Coordinate's. I want it to work with all of the 'Coordinate's. Although this would seem like it would work, it doesn't:

```
if(hex.getWorld().contains(tmp, true)) {
    System.out.println("break");
    break;
}
```

(if that is not valid code, just note it is not copied, I hand wrote it just now)
This is the code I am using in the area.

```
....
    tmp = new Coordinate();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        tmp.setX(Math.round((cam.direction.x * i) + cam.position.x));
        tmp.setY(Math.round(((cam.direction.y * i) + cam.position.y) / 0.578f));
        tmp.setZ(Math.round((cam.direction.z * i) + cam.position.z));

        //System.out.println(tmp.toString(false));
        //System.out.println(hex.getWorld().get(0).toString(false) + " - " + tmp.toString(false));
        System.out.println(hex.getWorld().contains(tmp, true));

        if(hex.getWorld().contains(tmp, false)){
            System.out.println("break");
            break;
        }
    }
//////////// BE-OND THIS POINT THE CODE IS CORRECT ////////////
    float slope = (cam.direction.z) / (cam.direction.x);
    if(spot != tmp){
        hex.instances.removeIndex(hex.instances.indexOf(i, true));
        spot = tmp;

        float size = 0.578f;
        float x = spot.getFormatedX(spot);
        float y = (spot.getY() * size);
        float z = spot.getFormatedZ(spot);
        i = new ModelInstance(hex.getHex("red"), x, y, z);
        i.transform.scale(size, size, size);
        hex.instances.add(i);
    }
....
```

That is being ran every game loop, and I know I should have it in my camera controller's `mouseMoved()` function I don't. The `hex` variable is also a custom class, but it would have nothing to do with the `Array` under `hex.getWorld()`. And the array is setup like this in the class:

```
Array<Coordinate> world = new Array<Coordinate>();
```

Comment: Did you write a proper .equals method for your Coordinate class?

Comment: I used a... let me check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that my `equals()` function in my `Coordinate` class took in

`equals(Coordinate coord){` instead of `equals(Object cord){`. That made it work.

Thank you, @Tenfour04, for your comment `Did you write a proper .equals method for your Coordinate class?`!